# Buffered writer when writing a line the line before gets removed and replaced by the new one

Tags: java

Hello new to over flow ^_^,
I have a write method and when I call it it writes but the line before gets removed and replaced by the new one.
My write method:

```
public void write(String args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()));
            writer.write(args);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you keep opening a new `FileWriter` in non-append (i.e. overwrite) mode each time you call your `write()` method.  Instead, try creating the `FileWriter` in append mode:

```
public void write(String args) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true));
        writer.write(args);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, it might make more sense for you to do all your write operations in a single go, which could eliminate the need for this method in the first place.  But if you want a helper method which can append to a file at certain times, then this answer should be helpful.

See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) for more information.

Comment: Of course one could argue that the whole method is quite useless, if you intend to write more than a single line in the file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen One more thing, if you have this
Students:
Name: nathaniel
Class: Yellow

and you want to read the values, ex name: nathaniel, how do you implement that with a buffered reader

Comment: This would require a non trivial amount a code, and it doesn't belong as a comment.  Try something, and if you get stuck then come back to SO and ask a new question.